# How to intercept multiple XHR requests with the same endpoint using cypress

Tags: cypress

For example, I have the following queries requests and each query returns a unique ID parameter that will be used later in another request. I used cypress for this but it intercepts only the first request and not the other for 4 requests.

How to make it intercept all requests and process each one of them separately?

```
describe(Cypress.env('label')+'TestSuite', function() { 

    beforeEach(function() {
            cy.login_api(Cypress.env('username'), Cypress.env('password'))
    })
    it('General data queries', function(){
        cy.visit(/)

        cy.intercept({method : 'GET',path : '/API/query/*'}).as('call1')
        cy.intercept({method : 'GET',path : '/API/query/*'}).as('call2')
        cy.intercept({method : 'GET',path : '/API/query/*'}).as('call3')
        cy.intercept({method : 'GET',path : '/API/query/*'}).as('call4')
        cy.intercept({method : 'GET',path : '/API/query/*'}).as('call5')

        cy.wait('@call1').then(res => {
            expect(res.response.statusCode).to.eq(200)
            const valuesV3 = res.response.body.values
        
            cy.setCookie('forceversion', '4')
            cy.intercept({method : 'GET',path : '/galileo/data/*'}).as('call11')
            cy.wait('@call11').then(res => {
                expect(res.response.statusCode).to.eq(200)
                const valuesV4 = res.response.body.values
                alert(vluesV4)
    
                for (var i = 0; i<Object.keys(valuesV3).length;i++) {
                    let x = Object.values(valuesV3[i])
                    let y = Object.values(valuesV4[i])
            
                    function compare(arr1, arr2) {
                        return arr1.every(item => arr2.includes(item))
                    }
                    if(compare(x,y)==true){
    
                        assert(true)
                    }
                    else {                
                 
                        assert(false)
                    })
                 
                }
           
            }
        
        })
        
    })
    
    })
})
```

Comment: Why not just add additional 4 wait commands to handle them?

Comment: @Zaista I add four waits but when i gonna to get the response i always get the response of the first request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single `intercept` command, call `visit` after `intercept` and don't nest the following `wait` commands. Try it like this:

```
it('General data queries', function() {
    cy.intercept({method : 'GET',path : '/API/query/*'}).as('call')
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.wait('@call').then((interception) => {
        cy.log(interception) // first api call
    })
    cy.wait('@call').then((interception) => {
        cy.log(interception) // second api call
    })
    cy.wait('@call').then((interception) => {
        cy.log(interception) // third api call
    })
})
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests#Waiting

Comment: Thanks for your reply but What if the number requests are changing from time to time. I mean that it can be 3 requests and can be 2 requests. What can i do so in this case ?

Comment: Since you have an indeterministic test that's a bit tricky to handle easily. If you really can't force your app to trigger expected number of responses (which should be your go-to solution), you can catch errors caused by those extra `wait` commands and explicitly ignore them using these examples: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__errors

Comment: It would be very unusual for an app to call it's API different number of times on different start-ups.